# If $x,y,z$ are in geometric progression ($x,y,z>0$) then

Tags: sequences-and-series

> $$\frac{1}{2x+\log_ex}, \frac{1}{4x+\log_ey}, \frac{1}{6x+\log_ez}$$ are in?

If I assume $x,y,z$ to be $e,e^2,e^3$ (I may be wrong) then
$$\frac{1}{2e+1},\frac{1}{4e^2+2}, \frac{1}{6e^3+3}$$

How is this supposed to form a harmonic progression? I may be wrong in considering them as $e$ but I saw a book doing that.

Comment: Please proofread your post.  It would also be helpful if you show some work you've done and write down your definition of harmonic progression and how you've tried to apply it to the given sequence.

Comment: I think the steps are just stating the obvious. I told what I assumed for x, y and z, and in the next line it’s very clear that I substituted the values. As a matter of fact, I didn’t even skip that many steps, just some boring calculations

Comment: I wasnt talking about your calculations; I was talking about your phrasing of the question in and immediately following the title, where there are no completed sentences.  But as the answer below shows, you did make mistakes in those "boring calculations" too.

Comment: Ofc I made mistakes in those boring calculations. That’s why I asked the question in the first place. I fail to see any problem with the title or phrasing. Forgive me for going straight to the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, let $y=xr, z=xr^2$.

Then the denominators of the three fractions are $$2x+\log x,4x+\log x+\log r,6x+\log x+2\log r,$$
i.e an AP with common difference $2x+\log r$. The fractions are therefore in harmonic progression.

N.B. In your try, you have substituted three different quantities for "$x$" i.e $e, e^2$ and $e^3$.